# What does "comment" means in NSLocalizedString(_:tableName:bundle:value:comment:)

Tags: swift, nslocalizedstring

I searched and read documentation for `NSLocalizedString(_:tableName:bundle:value:comment:)` method. But I am curious that what does **comment** parameter mean or is for in this method. I am using `NSLocalization` for the first time.

I tried using:

```
NSLocalizedString("Personal Information", comment: "abc")
```

and

```
NSLocalizedString("Personal Information", comment: "")
```

Both returned same string at the end.

Comment: it is a comment in the string files and is useful to identify or describe the actual usage of the string that will get localized

Comment: http://nshipster.com/nslocalizedstring/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create `*.strings` files using command line tool called `genstrings`, those comments will appear as comments above every entry. It can be used by translation team to know what is this string for.

Answer (score 1):

Th comment is just for the reference, consider you known only English, but translation team converts the text into French which you didn't know, you can search some text in French using this comment which is written in English. This comment can be written in some common language which is known very well by all.